# How do I get row values from row counts

Tags: c#, ms-access, rows

I am making a simple program to change access database to sql queries to import into sql database, I have no problem getting the names of the columns but when I try to get values of rows, it just becomes a huge confusing mess. Here is my full code just in case I did something wrong somewhere:

```
string table = "";
List<object> cols = new List<object>();
List<string> stringArr = new List<string>();
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    src = srcTxt.Text;
    table = tableCB.Text;
    string output = outTxt.Text;
    string scriptString = "";
    string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + src;
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = null;
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " + table, connection);
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();



        var tabName = reader.GetSchemaTable();
        var nameCol = tabName.Columns["ColumnName"];
        foreach (DataRow row in tabName.Rows)
        {
            cols.Add("`" + row[nameCol] + "`");
        }
        var result = string.Join(",", cols);



        scriptString = "INSERT INTO `" + table + "` (" + result + ") VALUES \n";


        int n = 0;
        while (++n < tabName.Rows.Count)
        {
            stringArr.Add("reader.GetString(" + n + ")");
        }

        var strValue = string.Join(",", stringArr);
        while (reader.Read())
        {

            scriptString += "(" + strValue + "),\n";
        }
    }
    File.WriteAllText(output, scriptString += ";");
}
```

but heres the code solely for the rows part:

```
int n = 0;
while (++n < tabName.Rows.Count)
{
    stringArr.Add("reader.GetString(" + n + ")");
}

var strValue = string.Join(",", stringArr);
while (reader.Read())
{

    scriptString += "(" + strValue + "),\n";
}
```

Some suggestions is very appreciated :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `stringArr.Add(reader.GetString(n));`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this result,I'm not sure.I hope this code helps you

```
string table = "";
List<object> cols = new List<object>();
List<string> stringArr = new List<string>();
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    src = srcTxt.Text;
    table = tableCB.Text;
    string output = outTxt.Text;
    string scriptString = "";
    string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + src;
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = null;
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " + table, connection);
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();



        var tabName = reader.GetSchemaTable();
        var nameCol = tabName.Columns["ColumnName"];
        foreach (DataRow row in tabName.Rows)
        {
            cols.Add("`" + row[nameCol] + "`");
        }
        var result = string.Join(",", cols);



        // scriptString = "INSERT INTO `" + table + "` (" + result + ") VALUES \n";


        // int n = 0;
        // while (++n < tabName.Rows.Count)
        // {
            // stringArr.Add("reader.GetString(" + n + ")");
        // }

        // var strValue = string.Join(",", stringArr);
        // while (reader.Read())
        // {

            // scriptString += "(" + strValue + "),\n";
        // }
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            scriptString += "INSERT  INTO `" + table + "` (" + result + ") VALUES \n (";
            int n = 0;
            while (++n < tabName.Columns.Count)
            {
                stringArr.Add(reader.GetValue(n).ToString());
            }
            var strValue = string.Join(",", stringArr);
            scriptString += strValue + "); \n";
        }

    }
    File.WriteAllText(output, scriptString += ";");
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you this was exactly what I was looking for! I shall mark this as answer!

Comment: By the way the `while (++n < tabName.Columns.Count)` should be `while (++n < tabName.Rows.Count)` or else it will throw an out of index error.